# how to add <Span> into a ng-template dynamically?

Tags: angular

Suppose that I have a ng-template in a component.

```
<ng-template #temp></ng-template>
```

suppose that I create the span dynamically.

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }

let lispan:HTMLSpanElement;
  lispan=this.renderer.createElement("span");
        lispan.innerHTML="ABC ABC"
```

Now How can we add above span into the ng-template dynamically?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Here you can see](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/common/src/directives/ng_template_outlet.ts#L63-L76) how `*ngTemplateOutlet` renders the template and retrieves the `viewRef` afterward. Here you can add more elements, but do so using `Renderer2`.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `<ng-template></ng-template>`, as mentioned [ng template docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ng-template#structural-directives), it is not rendered by default, you have to use structural direvtives to make it available in the dom.

Moreover `<ng-template></ng-template>` isn't rendered in the dom. So you have to use an HTML tag that is, like a `div`, then you can use `[innerHTML]="component_attribute_or_method"` directive, to render dynamicHTML

component.html

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="!(displaySpan$ | async); else temp">
  ...loading
</ng-container>
<ng-template #temp>
  <div [innerHTML]="span()"></div>
</ng-template>
<ng-template [ngIf]="displaySpan$ | async">
  <div [innerHTML]="span()"></div>
</ng-template>
```

component.ts

```js
@Component({...})
export class Component {
  displaySpan$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  span() {
    this.displaySpan$.next(true);
    return `
      <span>
        ABC
      </span>
    `;
  }
}
```